# Access 2010 - "Enter Paramater Value" error when trying to limit combobox selection based on another combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a form (frm_subscriptions) with two combo boxes at the top - cbx_financialYearFilter and cbx_subscriptionSearch. I would like to limit the selection of cbx_subscriptionSearch based on the selection of cbx_financialYearFilter.

I have attempted using the query below as the row source for cbx_subscriptionSearch:

```sql
SELECT tbl_subscriptions.Search, tbl_subscriptions.Financial_Year
FROM tbl_subscriptions
WHERE (((tbl_subscriptions.Financial_Year)=[Forms]![frm_subscriptions]![cbx_financialYearFilter]))
ORDER BY tbl_subscriptions.Search;
```

and have also set cbx_subscriptionSearch to requery on the after update event of cbx_financialYearFilter. This seems to be the suggested approach in most places I have looked (for example here: http://access-excel.tips/access-combo-box-value-depends-another/).

However in my case I am getting an "Enter Parameter Value" box for cbx_financialYearFilter. If I re-enter the financial year the filter works correctly, and if I cancel out the filter does nothing. Suggestions for solving this issue very welcome!

Thanks, Matt

Comment: Double-check form/field name. E.g. in the immediate window, does `Print [Forms]![frm_subscriptions]![cbx_financialYearFilter]` work? -- Is `cbx_financialYearFilter` perhaps on a subform?

Comment: Thanks Andre, that helped me to get on the right track! See answer below

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the control cbx_financialYearFilter did not need to be fully path referenced because the controls are all on the same form, so removing the FORMS group and reference to the specific form did the trick.

`SELECT tbl_subscriptions.Search
FROM tbl_subscriptions
WHERE (((tbl_subscriptions.Financial_Year)=[cbx_financialYearFilter]))
ORDER BY tbl_subscriptions.Search;`